# Upgraded MySQL 5.0 Linux -> MySQL 5.1 Windows and now query doesn't work

Tags: php, sql, mysql, pear

First of all, I know this SHOULDN'T work.  We're using a very old DAL/ORM (Pear/DB/GenericDao based) layer that incorrectly surmises that id is not an autoincrement/integer field.

**This statement DOES work in 5.0 Linux, DOES NOT work in 5.1 Windows.**  Is there a setting that could be different in my ini (ignore_type_errors="yes":))?  I really don't want to add rewriting/upgrading this DAL/ORM (which predates me at the company) to the server upgrade tasks.

Statement

```
INSERT INTO Party SET partyTypeID = 'PERSON',id = '',comment = '';
```

Error

```
Error Code: 1366
Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'id' at row 1)
```

DDL for Table

```
CREATE TABLE `Party` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `partyTypeID` varchar(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `comment` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `partyTypeID` (`partyTypeID`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=1017793 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Comment: Is any particular SQL Mode set ? (run `show variables like 'sql_mode'`);

Answer (score 4):

You are probably using a more strict SQL_MODE in 5.1 than you were using in 5.0, thus what used to be a warning is now an error.

What SQL_MODE are you using?

```
SELECT @@GLOBAL.sql_mode;
```

Here's an example to show how to get rid of the error:

```
mysql> set sql_mode = 'STRICT_TRANS_TABLES';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO Party SET partyTypeID = 'PERSON',id = '',comment = '';
ERROR 1366 (HY000): Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'id' at row 1
mysql> set sql_mode = '';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO Party SET partyTypeID = 'PERSON',id = '',comment = '';
Query OK, 1 row affected, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

mysql> show warnings;
+---------+------+------------------------------------------------------+
| Level   | Code | Message                                              |
+---------+------+------------------------------------------------------+
| Warning | 1366 | Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'id' at row 1 |
+---------+------+------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: That was it!  Thanks so much!  I am a little surprised that you can actually turn off type checking.